# Which model of trade is this?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, balance-of-trade

In [a recent article](http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2016/10/31/trade-plateaus-wonkish/), Paul Krugman showed these equations:

[image: Import share expressed in terms of $\alpha,\,\sigma,\,\tau,\,t$]

Which model is this? What do the symbols denote? Is the first symbol a v or nu?

Comment: Given the curl on the right, I see a $\nu$ (nu) not a $v$ (vee)

Comment: This question would be greatly improved by a link to Krugman's article.

Comment: @denesp As per your suggestion I've added a link, although it's an NYT piece so it may count towards peoples' articles per month limit.